# Fetch complex data from the internet

Tags: api, flutter, dart

am working on a machine app which fetches data from the server by using HTTP request. the problem is that the api is providing more than 50000 obejects **nested**. when i make the api request it takes more than 2 minutes. is there any solution so that i can fetch the data faster ?

P.s. I can't use pagination because am not gonna to build Listview with it. The fetched data are just there to be selected as property  not more.
So when user needs to configure machine, he will get more than 20 properties 3 of them are Lists that present the fetched data simple as Search list.

my data is somthing like this : every object has actually a list that contains at least 50 objects.

```
{
    "mainCategories": [
        {
            "mainCategoryName": "Agriculture",
            "labelDE": "Landtechnik",
            "labelEN": "Agriculture",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "categoryCode": "Tractor",
                    "categoryName": "Tractor",
                    "labelDE": "Traktor",
                    "labelEN": "Tractor",
                    "subCategories": [
                        {
                            "subcategoryCode": "Tractor",
                            "subcategoryName": "Tractor",
                            "labelDE": "Traktor",
                            "labelEN": "Tractor",
                            "subcategoryOptions": [
                                {
                                    "optionCode": "brand",
                                    "optionName": "brand",
                                    "LabelDE": "Hersteller",
                                    "LabelEN": "Make",
                                    "dataType": "Text"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionCode": "model",
                                    "optionName": "model",
                                    "LabelDE": "Modell",
                                    "LabelEN": "Model",
                                    "dataType": "Text"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionCode": "yearOfConstruction",
                                    "optionName": "yearOfConstruction",
                                    "LabelDE": "Baujahr",
                                    "LabelEN": "Year of Construction",
                                    "dataType": "int"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionCode": "powerHP",
                                    "optionName": "powerHP",
                                    "LabelDE": "Leistung in PS",
                                    "LabelEN": "Horse Power",
                                    "dataType": "int"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionCode": "additionalControlUnit",
                                    "optionName": "additionalControlUnit",
                                    "LabelDE": "Zusätzliche Steuergeräte",
                                    "LabelEN": "Additional Control Unit",
                                    "dataType": "enum",
                                    "enums": [
                                        {
                                            "enumCode": "mechanic",
                                            "enumName": "mechanic",
                                            "LabelDE": "mechanisch",
                                            "LabelEN": "mechanic"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "enumCode": "electric",
                                            "enumName": "electric",
                                            "LabelDE": "elektrisch",
                                            "LabelEN": "electric"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionCode": "hasCabin",
                                    "optionName": "hasCabin",
                                    "LabelDE": "Kabine vorhanden",
                                    "LabelEN": "Cabin",
                                    "dataType": "boolean"
                                },
                                {
                                    "optionCode": "airCondition",
                                    "optionName": "airCondition",
                                    "LabelDE": "Klimaanlage",
                                    "LabelEN": "Air Condition",
                                    "dataType": "boolean"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i using the following code :

```
static Future<http.Response> fetchDataFromApi(http.Client client) async {
    final response = await client.get(apiURL);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      modelMachineApi = new ModelMachineApi.fromJson(jsonResponse);
      print("The Api call has successed");
      print(modelMachineApi.categories[0].labelDE);
    }

   
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this  API call in Postman or anything similar?

Comment: For a better user experience you may need re-structure the api. first of all do not let them (users) wait for two minutes just for getting some random 50000 objects. make that selection box a search box and when a user enters a string call api directly and fetch and show it to users for selection.

Comment: @DarshShah yeah  it takes 25 sec. but i need it in the app not in Postman !!

Comment: If re-structuring the api is not an option, then you might consider prefetching the data(before the user needs it) and caching it for use later if it does not change oftenly

Comment: @HasilT i have actually thought about it, but the problem is that i don't have any access to the API. so i can't restructure it

Comment: Are you using any packages to get it? Like Dio or similar?

Comment: @VincentJ.Michuki  ja i have also thought about this option, the problem that the data gonne to be updated every day. but thank you for your advice

Comment: @DarshShah yes of course how should I fetch it otherwise! with the hand !!